# Android root permissions

Tags: android, certificate, root, android-source

Is there a way to get root permissions to an Android app?

If an app is signed with certificates from Google or from the device Producer can it have root permissions?

If so, how can I do this?

Comment: add android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" to your Manifest, that would give you the same privileges that system apps have. E.g. you should be able to read/write on Android internal storage etc. It's not Linux "root" though.

Comment: I get Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE

Comment: INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE should be caused by not signing the apk with the device system certificate - you will only get this if it's a custom rom with public sources or if you are the device producer.

Comment: I guess you have no way to have your app signed so the only thing you can do is to write an app that requires a rooted device. Such apps work by executing their commands through 'su'. See http://androidsu.com/superuser/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure if an application calls for root permissions in the end it's the OS on the device it needs to receive it from.  So the user would need a rooted device with superuser installed.  That's just part of the Android OS on the non rooted devices they are locked down to prevent possibly malicious code from running.

Comment: I want to know if this can be done by getting the app signed by the device producer or by google? And how?, if this is possible.

Comment: Not sure that is possible.  Like I said, no matter who the device manufacturer or provider is, it's the Android OS itself that locks down any root activity.  Thus why so many people root their phones.  However I have not looked at if it's even possible to get your app signed by Google.. There are apps that are very popular in the market that require root, and I'm sure if they could they would have gotten 'google signed'  so that's why I think it's just not possible.

Comment: Android's permission system is based on linux groups / users. E.g. the Android-"write sd card" permission will put an app that has this permission into the linux "write sd" group (each app has it's own user id). Also the filesystem has write-permissions only for that group. On an un-rooted Android there is no way to get linux-"root" in Android. As a device manufacturer you have to add some group and chown/chmod whatever you need access to.